# Lebesgue integrability on $[0,1]$ and sharp poles

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

We are working in the category of measurable (!) functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Clarifying the relationship between following two statements has already
caused me an immense amount of pain and humbled me in my mathematical
confidence, so I ask for your assistance.

Statement $A$: $\exists N\ \text{nullset }\forall x\in(0,1]\setminus N:\ f(x)\geqslant\frac{1}{x}$

Statement $B$: $f$ is not Lebesgue-integrable.

Obviously one has $A\Longrightarrow B$. But what about the converse
implication? I find it extremely hard to think about this and was
not able to find a proof nor a counterexample. The most confusing
point for me is that if a function $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable, the
also $\tilde{f}$, where $\tilde{f}$ is an arbitrary modification
of $f$ on a nullset, is integrable. Hence on a nullset I can make
$\tilde{f}$ bigger or smaller than my comparison function $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$
and still expect either the proof or the counterexample to te claim
$A\Longleftarrow B$ to go through for $\tilde{f}$, which makes the
presence of the nullset in statement $A$ necessary, but which also
makes thinking about all of this very confusing and hard!

Suppose a counterexample $f_{c}$ can be found, can we then further
find an $f_{c}$ that has no poles (i.e. there exist no $x_{0}\in[0,\infty)$
such that $\forall x_{0}\in X:\ \lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}f_{c}(x)\neq\pm\infty)$?
I am guessing that perhaps one can achieve this by finding a function
that oscillates sufficiently quickly, but I wasn't able to come up
with such a function.

Does anything change if we additionally assume $f$ to be non-negative?
I suppose not (i.e. if a proof or counterexample for non-negative
functions exists, one will also exist for an arbitrary function),
but again, I not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $1/(2x)$ as a very simple (if unsatisfying) counterexample.

For something measurable there's no way to have a problem from oscillation with the Lebesgue integral. There will have to be a blowup, although there doesn't really need to be existence of limits at any point, even after regularization by modification on a null set.

For example you could have $f(x)=\frac{1}{x} 1_{ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n}(x)$ where $I_n$ are disjoint intervals $(a_n,b_n)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(b_n/a_n)$ is divergent. For example, $b_n=e^{-2n},a_n=e^{-2n-1}$, then the integral on each $I_n$ is $1$. But for this $f$, $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$ doesn't exist even as $\pm \infty$. There is also no fixing that by modification on a null set because the intervals are separated from each other since $b_{n+1}<a_n$. This $f$ is also nonnegative.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I have a uestion though, after pondering it for a day:

Comment: You mentioned "For something measurable there's no way to have a problem from oscillation with the Lebesgue integral. There will have to be a blowup, although there doesn't really need to be existence of limits at any point, even after regularization by modification on a null set." Can you give me a link or a reference that contains a proof of these claims? It seems that the function $x\mapsto c \frac{1}{x}$ with $c>0$ is a kind of cut-off where if a function lies *strictly* below on a "sufficiently large" set it is L-integrable with finite integral. [...]

Comment: [...]  This seems to lie exactly at the heart of what I don't understand about Lebesgue-integrals. In your examples you are exactly using this fact BTW, that $f$ is either of the form $c\frac{1}{x}$ (first example) or  $0$ on a sufficiently large set (second example) to give a counterexample. It seems that this is the only way a function can fail to be L-integrable with finite integral?

Comment: @user38525 1. The Lebesgue integral is defined by integrating the positive part and the negative part separately and subtracting. The integrals of the parts exist (possibly as $+\infty$) as long as the function is just measurable. As a result the Lebesgue integral only fails to exist (again possibly as $\pm \infty$) if both parts have integral $+\infty$. 2. No, $\frac{1}{cx}$ is not the absolute wall either, as $\frac{1}{x\ln(|x|)}$ shows.

Comment: But if sharpen the requirement to assuming that $|f|$ instead of $f$ needs to be less than $c\frac{1}{x}$ then perhaps it might work? That would exclude your recent example. I have actually reformulated that in this new question, if you are interested (perhaps an opportunity for you to shoot down my propositions with more counterexamples ;) ): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4380127/reformulating-lebesgue-integrability-on-a-compact-set-as-a-condition-on-poles

Comment: @user38525 No, my example is negative but it doesn't matter if you take the absolute value.