# Reformulating Lebesgue integrability on a compact set as a condition on poles

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f:[0,1]→\mathbb{R}.$ I am interested in whether a criterion exists on the poles $f$ might have, that implies that $f$ has finite Lebesgue integral.

I am imagining something along the lines of following to hold: *Let $g(x):=c\frac{1}{x}$ for some $c>0$ and let $B_c\subseteq [0,1]$ be the "bad" set on which $|f|$ is greater than $g$. Then $f$ has finite Lebesgue integral if and only if $B_c$ is of at most measure $\varepsilon$ for some cleverly chosen $\varepsilon >0$ that somehow probably depends on $f$ and if the poles $f$ might have on $B_c$ are sufficiently "sharp"."*

One attempt in this direction was made in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4376228/lebesgue-integrability-on-0-1-and-sharp-poles) question that actually led me to formulate the above conjecture, after being confronted with some examples and counterexamples that sharpened my intuition.

Feel free to propose a better comparison function $g$, if counterexamples can be found for the current one. :)

---

My motivation comes from the following problem, for which I believe that assumptions may be too strong and the same conclusion can be inferred even if we weaken the assumptions: ***If a function $f:[0,1]→\mathbb{R}$ has finite Lebesgue integral then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $(0,1)$ converging to $0$ such that the sequence $(x_n f(x_n))$ converges also to $0$.***
*Since it is possible to prove it without any facts that use properties that are specific to the Lebesgue integral, but rather only that $f$ has to be smaller than $x\mapsto 1/x$ because of the assumption of finite Lebesgue integral (one arrives at this in two lines, by proof by contradiction), I feel that the statement that is to be proved is rather about poles a function might have than about it having finite Lebesgue integral. Now the question is if one can characterize the a function having finite Lebesgue integral in terms of those poles, as I tried to do above. If yes, that would vindicate assuming a finite Lebesgue integral; if not that would show that the assumption of the problem was too strong for its conclusion, as functions that don't have finite Lebesgue integral, yet still satisfy the above conclusion must exist.*

Comment: I don't know if this fits your purposes but define $E_{2^k} := \{ x : |f(x)| > 2^k \}$. Then, $f$ is integrable if and only if $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^km(E_{2^k}) < \infty$$. So, if $m(E_{2^k})$ does not decay quickly enough, $f$ fails to be integrable. Note also that The set of points where $|f|$ is infinite is exactly $$\bigcap_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} E_{2^k}$$

Comment: @fwd I like this a lot! This is actually pretty much exactly what I had in mind: It has a condition on the sharpness on the poles as well as on the size of the set where $f$ is "large". (Could you please give me a reference for this fact?) The only remaining question would now be how to use this theorem in order to determine whether the assumptions of my motivating problem can be weakened or not.

Comment: Incidentally, do you know if a similar criterion also holds for Riemann integrability?

Comment: This statement is in ch 2., exercise 10 in Stein & Shakarchi's Real Analysis. Since the Riemann integral is usually defined for bounded functions, I'm not sure such a criterion might exist for the Riemann integral.